# d3 custom order bar series with two categories

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I'm building a bar chart with dimplejs (d3.js) with 3 series (Contratado, Comprometido, Pago) by year and value. And I want that the bars will always have the same order like:

Contratado Comprometido Pago "By Year"

but the graph is ordering by value even if I add the sort order the graph will always change the place order...

```
//add the categories
x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Ano","Tipo"]);
//sort them
x.addOrderRule(["Contratado","Comprometido","Pago"]);}
//add the y axis
y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Valor");
//
all = myChart.addSeries("Tipo", dimple.plot.bar);
//sort
all.addOrderRule(["Contratado","Comprometido","Pago"]);
```

What I'm trying to get with the bars is always have this format:

Contratado / Comprometido / Pago  By Year

I change the legends to have this sort order, but I couldn't do the same with the bars...

Here is the fiddle link with the graph http://jsfiddle.net/beffes/noatfran/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dimple.axis.addGroupOrderRule](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#addGroupOrderRule) instead of series.addOrderRule. Your axis will have both a regular order rule :

```
x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Ano","Tipo"]);
x.addOrderRule("Ano");
```

which will order the groups by year, and a group order rule:

```
x.addGroupOrderRule(["Contratado","Comprometido","Pago"]);
```

which will order the bars within each group. You don't need a order rule for the series for this chart.